# How to Get Current Custom Post Type Associated Taxonomy Term

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a single.php file like below

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
            echo '<div">';
               the_content();
            echo '</div>';
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

now I need to get Current Custom Post Type Associated Taxonomy Term as link on the top of the page so if users click on the link the page navigate to taxonomy.php.

Can you please let me know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **get_the_term_list** within your loop to get the associated taxonomy term links:

```
global $post
$terms = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'your_taxonomy'); 
echo $terms;
```

This was a good solution for me as I only ever had a single taxonomy term associated to each post.